Edges sometimes not visible while in solid mode
If I stay in wireframe mode the edges are visible at all times, instead, if I go in solid mode and observe the object with a certain view (in the image: parallel to the y axis) the edges disappear. I could continue working in wireframe but I would like to understand why this happens since I am new to Blender and this could cause problems later on.

hello could you please share your object?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PwQ65NBqp5WS0une-ctBDm0-ixe1swgP/view?usp=sharing

maybe in that case enable the Shadow option of the Viewport Shading? or the Wireframe option of the Viewport Overlays?

Yes, with the wireframe option, I can see all edges, but I was trying to understand why this happens. I have experience with CAD software and there the edges are visible at all times independently of the current view.

Well, this is not CAD software... but if you want to see the wireframe, you can enable it - it's just not enabled by default. And the solid shading mode is not made to represent realistic lighting either, it shades a face according to its viewing angle, and when you look on faces pointing towards you with the exact same angle, they have the same shading. And even if they are on different levels with an orthogonal face separating them, this separation is not visible because in orthographic view looking "top down" on an orthogonal face makes it virtually invisible to the view.

@GordonBrinkmann Ok, thank you. If it is just the normal behavior of the software I will use wireframe mode without worrying about it.
